Quote about how familiar an unchristian town would be
I'm looking for a quote about how an unchristian town would look remarkably familiar - people would go to church, kids would obey their parents and there would be no swearing - but there would be no worship of God.
I think its from CS Lewis but I can't find it - anyone know what I'm referring to?
Merry Christmas!

Welcome to the site, Charles. There are several thousand of Lewis's quotes on the internet.  You need to search for yourself as what you have said here is too vague to home in on. To see what I mean go to this link:  https://www.azquotes.com/author/8805-C_S_Lewis/tag/christianity
